# PHP: Hide row if column returns empty or have specific value

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am stuck in this very basic stuff, hope you guys may be able to help me. I did try many solutions but none of them worked.

Through WordPress admin, I am generating the meta:

```
[
    'label' => __( 'Option A', ST_TEXTDOMAIN ),
    'id'    => 'custom_option_a',
    'type'  => 'text',
    'std'   => '0',
    'desc'  => __( 'Enter option A', ST_TEXTDOMAIN )
],
[
    'label' => __( 'Option B', ST_TEXTDOMAIN ),
    'id'    => 'custom_option_v',
    'type'  => 'text',
    'std'   => 'N/A',
    'desc'  => __( 'Enter option B', ST_TEXTDOMAIN )
],
[
    'label' => __( 'Option C', ST_TEXTDOMAIN ),
    'id'    => 'custom_option_c',
    'type'  => 'text',
    'std'   => 'N/A',
    'desc'  => __( 'Enter option C', ST_TEXTDOMAIN )
],
```

where 'std' => '0' returns blank or empty if not modified from backend and 
'std' => 'N/A' returns N/A

for output of described meta I have:

```
<table id="custitindetail" class="table abc-properties" data-toggle-section="abc-properties">
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo esc_html__( 'Option A', ST_TEXTDOMAIN ) ?></th>
        <td>
        <?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_option_a', true ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>               
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo esc_html__( 'Option B', ST_TEXTDOMAIN ) ?></th>
        <td>
        <?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_option_b', true ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>                           
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo esc_html__( 'Option C', ST_TEXTDOMAIN ) ?></th>
        <td class="cust_holiday_itinerary">
        <?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_option_c', true ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Now I want to hide the row if meta value in td is 0 or N/A either through PHP code using 'if empty' or jquery. Help me out please.

Thanks.

Comment: just add the condition in the if statement, just try it. `if (not 0 and not n/a)` or just query it directly, no more if conditions

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: using jQuery,  I have tried $("tr td:contains('N/A')").parent().hide(); and
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#custitindetail tr td").each(function() {
var cellText = $.trim($(this).text());
if (cellText.length == 0) {
$(this).parent().hide();
}
});
});
none worked, though they work fine on static content but i guess query loads before the content generates and thats why it isn't working.